# JavaScript multidimensional array using high order function like filter and length

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, higher-order-functions

I'm new to javascript and trying to figure out how to do the question below **using HOF with length property** but was not able to. My friends & I end up with other solution using counter during our class discussion. Would appreciate if you could help on ways to do the problem using length or maybe some other ways. Thank you!

Problem:
Each array in this array represents the each player's age in a soccer team
Filter out those teams that have less than 3 players that are older than 20 years old.
Hint: you can use higher order function (HOF) inside the callbacks of other HOFs.

Test case:
[[20,31,19,18,22],[20,31,16,21,21],[17,31,16,21,21],[18,19,19,20,32]]
to [[20, 31, 16, 21, 21], [17, 31, 16, 21, 21]]

Solution using counter:

```
Let currTeam = [[20,31,19,18,22],[20,31,16,21,21],[17,31,16,21,21],[18,19,19,20,32]];

let newTeam  = currTeam.filter(team => {
  let count = 0;
  team.map(age => {
    if (age > 20) count++;
  })
  if (count >= 3) return team;
})
```

Question - How to change the solution to use length property (other HOF is good too) instead using counter? Currently I use HOFs - filter and map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter each group, and check that it's length after filtering is greater than 2. Each group that fails the test would return `false`, and would be filtered by the main filter loop:

```js
const currTeam = [[20,31,19,18,22],[20,31,16,21,21],[17,31,16,21,21],[18,19,19,20,32]];

const newTeam  = currTeam.filter(team => 
  team.filter(age => age > 20).length > 2
);

console.log(newTeam);
```

If you don't won't to create intermediate arrays by using another filter, you can use `Array.reduce()` to count. The logical operation `(age > 20)` return a Boolean, and JS casts it to 0 for `false` and 1 for `true` when adding it to a number:

```js
const currTeam = [[20,31,19,18,22],[20,31,16,21,21],[17,31,16,21,21],[18,19,19,20,32]];

const newTeam  = currTeam.filter(team => 
  team.reduce((count, age) => count + (age > 20), 0) > 2
);

console.log(newTeam);
```

Notes:

1. Use `Array.map()` to transform the array's items, not for side effects like counting. For side effects, use `Array.forEach()`: `team.forEach(age => { if (age > 20) count++; })`
2. The `Array.filter()` method expects a Boolean value, so in your original code you can just use `return count >= 3;`